# Reading Sharepoint Online List Items using Client ID and Secret

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online

I am reading the sharepoint online list item using **SharePointPnPCoreOnline** as below. But it doesn't retrieve any items. Data count is always zero. Please let me know what I am missing.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using OfficeDevPnP.Core;
using System;

string siteUrl = "****";
string clientId = "*****";
string clientSecret = "******";

        using (var clientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))
        {
            clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, p => p.Title);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(clientContext.Web.Title);

            List sourceList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList");
            clientContext.Load(sourceList);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("GUID of List: " + sourceList.Id);

            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            ListItemCollection listItems = sourceList.GetItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.Load(listItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("Total Item Count of List: " + listItems.Count);
            foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
            {
                foreach (var field in listItem.FieldValues)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", field.Key, field.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

*Note: when I try the same set of code with username and password,I am able to retreive the items in the list.
And the Client ID and Secret are created in Azure.*

Comment: Are you sure those client and secret have all the access rights required to view those items?

Comment: Thanks Hirasawa for your response. Please let me know how to check the access rights as I don't have admin rights. But when I try the code "Console.WriteLine("GUID of List: " + sourceList.Id)" , I am getting the GUID of list. And when I try the code "Console.WriteLine("Total Item Count of List: " + listItems.Count);", I am getting the count as zero only.

Comment: use the appinv.aspx page to set the policy for the app - the example would give access to read in the SC  <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="Read" />
</AppPermissionRequests>